# ¿Como agregar un guion cada 4 caracteres?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo una duda y es ver si se puede separar con guiones en un JTextField destinado para numeros telefonicos, pero no se como, lo que busco es que al escribir 4 numeros aparesca un guion y los separe de los numeros que quedan en el JTextField.

0568-8884433

Que sean separados de esta manera, el guion no lo debe escribir el usuario, debe aparecer al escribir los 4 primeros numeros o si se puede que el guion este fijo allí

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo?

Comment: la verdad no he intentado nada, no se que propiedad usar para ingresar el guion de manera automatica despues de escribir los 4 caracteres

Comment: Con los String puedes extraer el tamaño de este, hacer subcadenas  y concatenaciones de texto. Con estas tres herramientas podrás hacerlo. Inténtalo y si no te sale, ya pones el código por aquí.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar un control `JFormattedTextField` y en la propiedad `formatterFactory` eliges `mask` y la estableces como `###-#######`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Te invito a leer [answer], además puedes hacer el [tour] para que aprendas cómo funciona el sitio y ganarás tu primera medalla. Tu respuesta tiene deficiencias de formato, si crees que puedes mejorarla te invito a hacerlo pulsando en el botón [edit]. Saludos